# Use the new Express Checkout view with Adaptive Payments

Tags: php, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I have a website that uses adaptive payments to act as the middle man between sellers and buyers, and I have been using the standard PayPal view for a while now that looks like this:

[image]

This view has always been fine for me, although it is pretty ugly.. but I've started noticing websites with checkout pages that look like this:

[image]

This checkout page looks way better, and I have searched everywhere to find out how to implement it into my adaptive payments api. Based off of what I've found it is only available on express checkouts.

Is there any way I could get my checkout page to look like this without having to rework the whole PayPal API for my site?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of now, the checkout experience you're seeing with Adaptive is all you're going to get.  The Express Checkout experience is indeed much better, and it always has been.  I've always recommended to stick with EC as much as possible.

There's really nothing you can do in Adaptive that you can't do in EC, it's just a different series of steps to get it done.